# How can I produce a table of transition types in R?

Tags: r, dynamic, time-series, data-analysis

I have some data which has a number of different id's in it and a list of their states at different times  (t1, t2, t3 etc) and I'd like to generate a table that gives information about the different types of state change that happen, so something that would look like this for the sample data (copied below).

```
  x  y  z
x 0  2  0
y 1  2  1
z 1  0  2
```

Which would show, for example, that `x` changed to `y` twice and `y` changed to `x` once. Does anyone know how I might be able to do this in R?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
id <- c('a','b','c')
t1 <- c('x','y','z')
t2 <- c('y','y','z')
t3 <- c('z','y','x')
t4 <- c('z','x','y')
df <- cbind(id, t1, t2, t3, t4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can do this is by using `igraph`. The slightly tricky bit is getting it in a graph format, but after that is done the adjacency matrix can be extracted.

```
# Split matrix so that each row is a `path`
lst <- split(df[,-1], 1:nrow(df))
unique_nodes <- unique(c(df[,-1]))

library(igraph)

# Create empty graph and name nodes
g <- make_empty_graph(n=length(unique_nodes))
V(g)$name <- unique_nodes

# Read in each path
for (i in lst) {
  g <- g + path(i)
}

# Output adjacency matrix
as_adj(g, sparse=FALSE)
#  x y z
#x 0 2 0
#y 1 2 1
#z 1 0 2
```