# How to transform a table of an hierarchical network to an edge list efficiently in R

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

I know there are plenty of open and answered questions about generating edge lists but I found none that fits my case:

I have a table that represents a strictly hierarchical network and I want to convert it to one that has 3 columns: source node, target node and type of interaction. The table is fairly redundant with the first column listing all first level nodes, second column being all corresponding second level nodes, and so on:

```
  first second third
1     A      F     L
2     B      F     L
3     C      G     L
4     D      F     L
5     E      G     L
6     L      L     L
```

For a visualization of the network see the image below:
[image: Hierachial Network]

The table I want looks like this:

```
  source target  level
1      F      L  third
2      G      L  third
3      L      L  third
4      A      F second
5      B      F second
6      C      G second
7      D      F second
8      E      G second
9      L      L second
```

So far, I only had to do it once with fairly few levels, so I used the following clumsy approach with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
example.df <- data.frame(
  "first"  = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "L"),
  "second" = c("F", "F", "G", "F", "G", "L"),
  "third"  = c("L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L")
)
name.v <- c("source","target")
third.df <- example.df %>% 
  group_by(second) %>% 
  summarise(third = unique(third))
names(third.df) <- name.v
second.df <- example.df %>% 
  group_by(first) %>% 
  summarise(second = unique(second))
names(second.df) <- name.v
hier.df <- bind_rows("third" = third.df, "second"= second.df, .id = "level") %>% 
  select(source, target, level)
# using igraph to generate the image
library(igraph)
hier.graph <- graph_from_data_frame(hier.df)
plot(hier.graph)
```

Obviously, this would scale pretty badly. So for programming, I would prefer to find a more lean approach, e.g. in base R.

Comment: are you actually wanting the intermediate table, or do you just want an easy way to turn it in to an igraph object. If the second [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300747/how-can-i-produce-a-table-of-transition-types-in-r/46301272#46301272) can help

Comment: I want the table. I just used igraph for illustration. I will edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `map_df` here

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="  first second third
A      F     L
B      F     L
C      G     L
D      F     L
E      G     L
L      L     L", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Solution

```
library(purrr)
map_df(2:ncol(df), ~select(df, (.x-1):.x) %>% setNames(c("source", "target")), .id="id") %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    distinct() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(id = colnames(df)[as.numeric(id)+1])

# A tibble: 9 x 3
      # id source target
   # <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
# 1 second      A      F
# 2 second      B      F
# 3 second      C      G
# 4 second      D      F
# 5 second      E      G
# 6 second      L      L
# 7  third      F      L
# 8  third      G      L
# 9  third      L      L
```

This scales with arbitrary number of columns

```
set.seed(1)
new_df <- as_tibble(matrix(sample(LETTERS, 25, replace=FALSE), ncol=5)) %>%
        setNames(c("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"))

myfun <- function(data) {
    map_df(2:ncol(data), ~select(data, (.x-1):.x) %>% setNames(c("source", "target")), .id="id") %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        distinct() %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(id = colnames(data)[as.numeric(id)+1])
}
myfun(new_df)

# A tibble: 20 x 3
       # id source target
    # <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
 # 1 second      G      S
 # 2 second      J      W
 # 3 second      N      M
 # 4 second      U      L
 # 5 second      E      B
 # 6  third      S      D
 # 7  third      W      C
 # 8  third      M      Y
 # 9  third      L      V
# 10  third      B      X
# 11 fourth      D      F
# 12 fourth      C      H
# 13 fourth      Y      I
# 14 fourth      V      P
# 15 fourth      X      K
# 16  fifth      F      Z
# 17  fifth      H      Q
# 18  fifth      I      O
# 19  fifth      P      A
# 20  fifth      K      R
```

Answer (score 2):

`igraph`'s `as_data_frame()` will take care of this for you. `what` can be `"edges"`, `"vertices"` or `"both"`, which will return both vertices and edges in a `list` of `data.frame`s.

`?igraph::as_data_frame`

```
igraph::as_data_frame(x = hier.graph, what = "edges") %>%
`colnames<-`(c("source", "target", "level"))

# source target  level
# 1      F      L  third
# 2      G      L  third
# 3      L      L  third
# 4      A      F second
# 5      B      F second
# 6      C      G second
# 7      D      F second
# 8      E      G second
# 9      L      L second
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is clumsy too, but columns 1 & 2 make the second level connections; columns 2 & 3 are the third level.  Just separate them and use `rbind`.

```
SL = unique(cbind(TAB[,1:2], "second"))
names(SL) = c("source", "target", "level")

TL = unique(cbind(TAB[,2:3], "third"))
names(TL) = c("source", "target", "level")

rbind(TL, SL)
   source target  level
1       F      L  third
3       G      L  third
6       L      L  third
11      A      F second
2       B      F second
31      C      G second
4       D      F second
5       E      G second
61      L      L second
```

## DATA

```
TAB = read.table(text="first second third
1     A      F     L
2     B      F     L
3     C      G     L
4     D      F     L
5     E      G     L
6     L      L     L",
header=TRUE)
```